# ccxt.Bitmex params problem with fetch_markets()

Tags: ccxt

I am trying to recover the Bitmex futures markets with CCXT and can get the right filters working with this code:

`response_object = requests.get("https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument/active?typ=FFCCSX")`

the typ=FFCCSX filters for the futures market before returning the response object.

When I use CCXT to pull the data, I am adding the parameters, but it returns the full market each time e.g.:

```
params = {'typ':'FFCCSX'}
response = bitmex.exchange.fetch_markets(params)
```

I would be really grateful for a steer as to where I am going wrong.